# HTML ordered list with custom text

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>testing</li>
    <li>hello world</li>
</ol>
```

This, of course, works and gives the following output:

```
1. foo
2. bar
3. testing
4. hello world
```

Now my problem is that I sometimes need to have different text instead of the numbers. The text should be completely customizable, so CSS `:before` solutions don't work for me.

Consider this example, a listing of TV series episodes:

```
    12. The Duel
    13. Prince Family Paper
14./15. Stress relief
    16. Lecture Circuit: Part 1
```

So essentially I'm trying to create a "fake" `<ol>` so that all the text after the numbers is correctly aligned. Is there any way I can achieve this in HTML/CSS?

Comment: @AymDev my question is literally how to do it myself, since I don't know how. Note that I also have to display text between the bullet points, and that this text also needs to be lined up. I don't think this is a trivial task and I would like to kindly ask the downvoters to explain why they did so.

Comment: @AymDev This doesn't fulfill my requirements (see https://jsfiddle.net/j0shey6f/). The text isn't aligned properly

Comment: I'm sorry but what you're saying doesn't make any sense. I encountered a non-trivial problem and, after doing extensive research, decided to ask a question about it. I was under the impression that that's precisely what Stackoverflow is for. I am well aware of both basic and advanced techniques in HTML and CSS, I just couldn't find a solution to fit my needs myself. Seeing as even Stackoverflow supposedly currently has no answer for this particular question (remember, the text I'm trying to display is dynamic), I think it could even benefit the community in one way or another.

Comment: Downvoting just because a problem APPEARS to be trivial is a fundamentally wrong approach in my opinion. I imagine you found this question, thought "this idiot wants a complete solution for a simple task, probably homework" and promptly downvoted. As it turns out, you don't even seem to have an answer to the problem (which is fine, but that means you really shouldn't downvote because the question is "trivial"). If your motivations were otherwise, please feel free to explain yourself. I always have an open ear for constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will have to solve it with a table without borders. Align the first tds to the right and the second ones to the left. Is what I think that would most closely resemble what you want.

Something like:

css:

```
table {
    border: none;
}
table tr td:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>12.</td>
    <td>The Duel</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>13.
    <td>Prince Family Paper
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>14./15.</td>
    <td>Stress relief</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>16.</td>
    <td>Lecture Circuit: Part 1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! I'm a bit hesitant to use table solutions, but as long as it works I'm fine with it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. I still think there was no need for the 3 downvotes though.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote. And yes, I also like to avoid tables, but sometimes they are our best friends. xP